# Create new edge between list of nodes if there is a path between them - networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I would like to have an edge when there is a path between nodes when there is a path(reachability) between nodes.

Let's say I have the following graph.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(10, pr = 1)
G.add_node(20, pr = 2)
G.add_node(30, pr = 3)
G.add_node(40, pr = 2)

G.add_node(50, pr = 3)
G.add_node(60, pr = 1)

G.add_edges_from([(10,20),(10, 30),(10, 40),(10, 50),(20,30), (30,40), (40, 50), (50,60)])

nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, pos = nx.circular_layout(G),node_size =800)
```

[image]

I am planning to get the following graph as output. I would like to filter nodes with the attribute (pr==1 and pr ==2) and ignoring (pr==3). Since there a path from node 10 to 40, I would like to create a new edge (10, 40) during filtering.

[image]

Here is how I tried to approach.

```
collector = nx.DiGraph()
for n1, atrr1 in G.nodes(data ='True'):
    for n2, atrr2 in G.nodes(data ='True'):
        if ((G.node[n1]['pr'] ==1) & (G.node[n1]['pr'] ==2)):

            if (has_path(G,n1, n2)):
                collector.add_edge(n1,n2)

        if ((G.node[n1]['pr'] ==1) & (G.node[n2]['pr'] ==2)):

            if (has_path(G,n1, n2)):
                collector.add_edge(n1,n2) 

        if ((G.node[n2]['pr'] ==2) & (G.node[n2]['pr'] ==1)):

            if (has_path(G,n1, n2)):
                collector.add_edge(n1,n2) 


nx.draw(collector, with_labels = True, pos = nx.spring_layout(collector))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [6,6]
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

It is doesn't seem complex but I couldn't figure out it. Could anyone help me?

Comment: use `print()`  to see values in variables in different moments and places - it can help to see where they has wrong values

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to compute the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_graph_theory) of your graph.  That is, a graph G* which models your input graph G but additionally has edges between nodes if there is a path between them. Networkx provides this functionality on an input graph with [transitive_closure(G)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_closure.html).